# How to Create hierarchical Item source for my hierarchial datatemplate from datatable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to make a hierarchical item source from a datatable whose fields are(Unique_id,Lookup_Value,Parent_Id,Is_Parent,Category_Level) where each record either be a parent or child. I'm trying with recursion but multilevel cannot be achieved. How can it be?

1.first i have filtered all parent nodes where is_parent=true;
2.i have passed each root to a recursive method for finding its child.

i have achieved two level.

```
private void CreateHierarchicalScanningCategory(DataTable scanningcategory)
        {
            Task<List<ScanningMenuItem>> scaningmenuitem =
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => CreateHierarchicalTemplate(scanningcategory));
        }

        private List<ScanningMenuItem> CreateHierarchicalTemplate(DataTable scanningcategory)
        {
            Func<DataRow, ScanningMenuItem, ScanningMenuItem> _funcfor_parentchild = null;

            _funcfor_parentchild = (parentrow, menuitem) =>
            {
                var childrows = this._scanning_Category.AsEnumerable().Where
                (row => Convert.ToInt32(row["Parent_Id"]) == Convert.ToInt32(parentrow["Gen_Lookup_Id"]));

                if (childrows != null && childrows.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var item in childrows)
                    {
                        var foo = new ScanningMenuItem { Title = Convert.ToString(item["Lookup_Value"]) };
                        menuitem.Items.Add(foo);

                        _funcfor_parentchild(item, menuitem);
                    }
                }

                return menuitem;
            };
            var parentnodes = scanningcategory.Copy().AsEnumerable().Where(row => Convert.ToBoolean(row["Is_Parent"]) == true);

            if (parentnodes.Any())
            {
                List<ScanningMenuItem> menuitem = new List<ScanningMenuItem>();
                foreach (var item in parentnodes)
                {
                    ScanningMenuItem root = new ScanningMenuItem { Title = Convert.ToString(item["Lookup_Value"]) };

                    var node_menuitem = _funcfor_parentchild(item, root);
                    menuitem.Add(node_menuitem);
                }
              return menuitem;
            }

            return null;
        }

ScanningMenuItem:

 public class ScanningMenuItem
    {
        public ScanningMenuItem()
        {
            this.Items = new ObservableCollection<ScanningMenuItem>();
        }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ScanningMenuItem> Items { get; set; }
    }

Datatable structure:

   DataTable dt = new DataTable
            {
                Columns = { { "Unique_id", typeof(int) }, 
                    {"Lookup_Value" },  {"Parent_Id",typeof(int) },
                    { "Is_Parent",typeof(int) }, {"Category_Level",typeof(int) } }
            };

            dt.Rows.Add(150,  "EMR",0,1,1);
            dt.Rows.Add(100361,  "Cardiology",150,0,2);
            dt.Rows.Add(100362,  "Gastrology",150,0,2);
            dt.Rows.Add(152,  "Discharge Summary",0,1,1);
            dt.Rows.Add(1385,"Investigations/Procedures", 0, 1, 1);
            dt.Rows.Add(1700,  "DENTAL",0,1,1);
            dt.Rows.Add(633671,  "EMR2",0, 1,1);
            dt.Rows.Add(151,  "FO",0, 1,1);
            dt.Rows.Add(117370,"External Sick Leave",151, 0, 2);
            dt.Rows.Add(117371,"External Appointment",151, 0, 2);
            dt.Rows.Add(117372,"Heart Transplantation",100361, 0, 3);
```

The Datatable is dynamic. don't know how many levels are coming.

```
1.EMR
 1.1 Cardiology
   1.1.1 Heart Transplantation
 1.2 Gastrology
2.FO
 2.1 External Appointment
 2.2 External Appointment
3.EMR2
 3.1 Discharge
 3.2 DENTAL
 3.3 Investigations/Procedures"`enter code here`
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Would you mind cleaning up the post and code a bit so we can help out?

Comment: I started trying to get the code running in dotnetfiddle, but I'm not sure how it even compiles. Feel free to get it compiling there and then re-post here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8XkSxO

Comment: It is the essence. I'm stucked with the recurtion section.

Comment: can you run it in visual studio

Comment: Out of the blue I'd say you have to extract the part which handles **one** parent element into a separate method and call this method for each parent element and inside this method for each child element recursively.